# Expression technique désignant le bétail

Tags: choix-de-mot, zoologie

Est-il *correct* d'employer le terme « animaux domestiques de production » au lieu de « le bétail et les volailles », d'un point de vue technique ?

Comment: Peut-être *animaux d'élevage* ? Je ne suis pas sûr de bien comprendre la portée de la question.

Comment: Merci de nous préciser en quoi ces termes sont-ils techniques.

Comment: @Zistolen Je veux dire, est-ce grammaticalement correct?

Comment: @MohammadSanei: Ok, dans ce cas, je pense que `animaux d'élevage` comme l'a suggéré Stéphane Gimenez est plus correct que `animaux domestiques de production`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'expression est grammaticalement correcte, mais je pense qu'elle ne convient pas sémantiquement. *Domestique*, appliqué pour des animaux, signifie en général des animaux qui sont élevés dans des maisons par des non-professionnels : chats, chiens, lapins, etc. Les animaux comme les bœufs et les poules sont des *espèces domestiquées* mais pas des *animaux domestiques*. Lorsqu'un animal est élevé pour sa production, on ne parle en général pas d'animal domestique mais d'*[animal de production](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/animal_de_production)*. Le [sens juridique d'*animal domestique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_domestique_en_droit_fran%C3%A7ais) inclut les animaux d'élevage, mais je pense que le sens courant est différent.

Cela dit, Wiktionnaire définit *animal de production* comme « animal domestique élevé par l'homme pour ses productions ». Je trouve cela étrange, à la fois parce qu'« animal domestique » n'évoque pas l'élevage et parce qu'une espèce non domestiquée (pas d'évolution génétique) mais élevée par l'homme peut quand même être un animal de production.

Je recommande donc *animaux d'élevage* ou *animaux de production*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally "Animal de production" make me think about a horse or an ox pulling the cart.

The term "Animaux domestique de production" referring to cattle and poultry is only used in statistical data and technical economic books. In other contexts, "Animal d'élevage" will not make the person to whom your are talking have to think hard about what your are meaning.

If you are in a farm and do not expect the animal to panic when it sees you, you can use the term "Animal domestique". And if it's a pet living in your house, use the term "Animal famillier". [I know it should be the reverse, but...].

Comment: -1, those are not the technical terms, which is what the OP asks for.

Comment: As I explained (tried to explain), if by technical term you mean "to be used in statistical data and economic book" then you have a chance to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

As a translator, when an expression I need to check gives only 6 outdated results on the Internet, I usually look for another option.

It is the case with "animaux domestiques de production".

It all depends on the kind of animals being considered.
Would guinea pigs, bees, silkmoths, goldfish and donkeys enter the category ?

Food production legislation, if it is the case here, is extremely abondant and can vary according to the country. The best thing to do is to check the oficial terminology used in the country that interests you.

If there is no termilogy obligation, I suppose "Bétail et volailles" is OK, but fish are excluded.
"Bétail, volaille et produits de la pêche et de la mer" still excludes certain categories (river breeding), but is explicit and sufficiently exhaustive for a non-technical audience. I'd go for that one.